# Howto intercept intents (for calendar event creation)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like to create a custom way to enter new events to the calendar.

From what I understood it should be easy by creating an app responding to the intent being sent by the calendar app. I created the following activity in my app:

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- for normal launch --> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
       <!-- also tried DEFAULT and others -->
       <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But still only the builtin dialog pops up. From what I've seen in the sources of the calendar app the Intent isn't hardcoded there.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging in the source code I found out that the intent target class is hardcoded. So no way of overriding the event edit activity. ;-(

Comment: Nothing change since the question date?